# Update string at a specific line so it doesn't update duplicates in string?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I know how to go to a specific line but I don't know how to update that specific line in the string. I have tried the Replace functionality but it overwrites the duplicates as well. Any ideas?

```
  static string GetLine(string text, int lineNo)
  {
     string[] lines = text.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');
     return lines.Length >= lineNo ? lines[lineNo - 1] : null;
  }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   string file = "D:\\random.text";
   string contents = "";
   string text="random";
   contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
   finale=GetLine(contents,lines);
   // Console.ReadLine();
    if(finale.Contains(text))
    {
        finale.Replace(text,"Random");
        System.Console.WriteLine(finale);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
```

Comment: `lines` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable type which means you cant alter an existing string. `string.Replace` returns the replaced string and you need to assign it back.

```
if(finale.Contains(text))
{
    finale = finale.Replace(text,"Random"); //<- note here
    System.Console.WriteLine(finale);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

From there you need to rebuild the string from the string array as noted by Philippe. A complete example (but untested):

```
  static string[] GetLines(string text)
  {
     return text.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');
  }

  static string GetLine(string[] lines, int lineNo)
  {
      return lines.Length >= lineNo ? lines[lineNo - 1] : null;
  }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   string file = "D:\\random.text";
   string contents = "";
   string text="random";
   contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
   var lines = GetLines(contents);
   finale = GetLine(lines, lineNo);
   //Console.ReadLine();
   if (finale == null)
       return;
    if(finale.Contains(text))
    {
        finale = finale.Replace(text, "Random");
        System.Console.WriteLine(finale);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    lines[lineNo] = finale;
    contents = string.Join('\n', lines);
 }
```

And best of all, you don't need all that split function at all. .NET has that functionality and it does *lazily* (on demand) which is a bonus.

See for [**File.ReadLines**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you're using .NET 4.0 and above.

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for.thanks alot..:)..you also solved my string assignment problem.:)...

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to keep the array returned by Split and then use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to rebuild what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild the string with string builder as you read the file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = "D:\\random.txt";
    string find = "random";
    string replace = "Random";

    StringBuilder resultList = new StringBuilder();
    using (var stream = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        while (stream.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string line = stream.ReadLine();
            if(line == find)
            {
                line = replace;
            }

            resultList.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    string result = resultList.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.Read();
}
```